# Android: Remove only bottom FadingEdge effect from scroll bar

Tags: android, scrollview

I know how to disable fadingedge from scrollbar but what I need is to disable just the bottom fading edge without disabling the top fading edge effect, is that possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you want by extending the ScrollView and overriding one of those two methods:

```
float getTopFadingEdgeStrength()
float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength()
```

They'll alow you to change the size of the fading edge - just set bottom value to 0 and you are ready to go :)

Code example with bottom fading turned off:

```
/**
 * Created by scana on 14.12.14.
 */
public class TopFadeEdgeScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe the question is not clear, I want to be able to disable it and enable it, not disable the bottom fading edge all the time, in other words, I want to disable the bottom fading when the user at a certain point from the scroll view and enable it when he/she is above it

Comment: This is really simple, just add the variable which you will modify by some kind of setter. You could listen for the Y value in some OnScrollListener and modify the value returned by getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() method. 0 value means no fading edge at all, 1 means it is fully visible. I can provide an example if you 'd like :)

Answer (score 0):

scana's answer is correct.
Here's a Kotlin version of his answer that has methods to disable specific edges.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.ScrollView

class FadingEdgeScrollView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : ScrollView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    var topFadingStrength: Float? = null
    var bottomFadingStrength: Float? = null
    var leftFadingStrength: Float? = null
    var rightFadingStrength: Float? = null


    override fun getTopFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return topFadingStrength ?: super.getTopFadingEdgeStrength()
    }

    override fun getBottomFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return bottomFadingStrength ?: super.getBottomFadingEdgeStrength()
    }

    override fun getLeftFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return leftFadingStrength ?: super.getLeftFadingEdgeStrength()
    }

    override fun getRightFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return rightFadingStrength ?: super.getRightFadingEdgeStrength()
    }

    fun disableTopFade() {
        topFadingStrength = 0f
    }

    fun disableBottomFade() {
        bottomFadingStrength = 0f
    }

    fun disableLeftFade() {
        leftFadingStrength = 0f
    }

    fun disableRightFade() {
        rightFadingStrength = 0f
    }
}
```